# SpriteKit pause Scene (Swift4.2)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I built a Game with a pause button which shows a new modal ViewController with a Pause menu over the current and pauses the scene with the following  function (which is located in the scene and called via protocol and delegate):

```
func pause(isPaused: Bool) {
    let pauseAction = SKAction.run {
        self.view?.isPaused = isPaused
    }
    self.run(pauseAction)
}
```

Pausing the scene and showing the modal view controller works, but when I return to the scene by a unwind segue the scene doesn't unpause.

The pause button is in the same view as the scene.
For communication with the scene from the Pause menu, I use an unwind segue where I call the pause function via Protocol and delegate.

I present the pause menu with that:

```
@IBAction func PauseMenuButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PauseMenuVC")

    vc.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
    vc.definesPresentationContext = true
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    SceneIsPausedDelegate.pause(isPaused: true)
}
```

and go back to the scene with that :

```
@IBAction func unwindToGameVC(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    SceneIsPausedDelegate.pause(isPaused: false)
}
```

I think that the function is never called because it is in the scene since it is paused the is no execution.

Comment: Show how you present the modal, and do you call this function again with `isPaused = false` later, to unpause it? Just because you pause something, doesn't imply that it gets unpaused whenever you remove a view. You have to explicitly state what you want to do.

Comment: It seems like I was unclear with that, I corrected my question.

Comment: Is your unwind method being called - if you add a print statement, does it get called?

Comment: yes aaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: Instead of running actions, i would just do sceneView.pause() and sceneView.play()

Comment: That is, if you are using SceneView

Comment: Gonna put it as answer then *thumbs up*

Comment: you can't use an action to unpause, the action will never run.  That is like freezing time, and expecting a person frozen in time to unfreeze it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed:

```
func pause(isPaused: Bool) {
    let pauseAction = SKAction.run {
    self.view?.isPaused = isPaused
}
    self.run(pauseAction)
}
```

to:

```
func pause(isPaused: Bool) {
    self.view?.isPaused = isPaused
}
```

it wokes without an action.

Answer (score 1):

`SKView` pause and `SKScene` pause behave differently

When an `SKView` is paused, it will not call the update functions on the scene

When an `SKScene` is paused, `SKView` will still call the update functions on the scene, and the scene will not call the update functions on the children nodes.

In your scenario, you are calling pause on the `SKView`.  This means any action you run on your scene will not fire because update never happens.

I recommend either switching to `SKScene` pause, or not using an action to pause and unpause.